# Splunk Log Displaying as Hex When Using Logback SSLSocketAppender

Tags: java, ssl, logback, splunk

I am trying to use Splunk to collect logs for my app. I set up TCP data input on port 6514 (with SSL enabled on this port). From my Java application, I am able to connect to the port and send logs. However, when I check these logs on Splunk web, it displays as Hex format.

**LOGBACK CONFIGURATION**

```
<configuration debug="true">

 <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{ISO8601} [%thread] [%cyan(%C.%M\(\))] [%highlight(%level)] : %msg - %ex{short} %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="sslsocket" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SSLSocketAppender">
    <remoteHost>127.0.0.1</remoteHost>
    <port>6514</port>
    <queueSize>20</queueSize>
    <reconnectionDelay>20</reconnectionDelay>
    <ssl>
        <trustStore>
            <location>file:///path/to/truststore.jks</location>
            <password>truststorepassword</password>
        </trustStore>
    </ssl>
</appender>

<logger name="splunk.secure.logger" additivity="false" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="sslsocket"/>
</logger>

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

**USAGE**

public class Starter {

```
private final static org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("splunk.secure.logger");


public static void main(String[] args) {
    logger.info("Testing SSL Socket Appender Log");
}

}
```

**LOG BACK DEBUG OUTPUT TO CONSOLE**

```
11:00:04,701 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - 
About to instantiate appender of type 
[ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SSLSocketAppender]
11:00:04,720 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - 
Naming appender as [sslsocket]
11:00:04,763 |-INFO in 
ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type 
[ch.qos.logback.core.net.ssl.SSLConfiguration] for [ssl] property
11:00:04,776 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.core.net.ssl.KeyStoreFactoryBean] for 
[trustStore] property
11:00:06,035 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SSLSocketAppender[sslsocket] - SSL protocol 'SSL' provider 'SunJSSE version 1.8'
11:00:06,045 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SSLSocketAppender[sslsocket] - trust store of type 'JKS' provider 'SUN version 1.8': file:///path/to/truststore.jks
11:00:06,046 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SSLSocketAppender[sslsocket] - trust manager algorithm 'PKIX' provider 'SunJSSE version 1.8'
11:00:06,063 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SSLSocketAppender[sslsocket] - secure random algorithm 'SHA1PRNG' provider 'SUN version 1.8'
11:00:06,556 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [splunk.secure.logger] to INFO
11:00:06,557 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [splunk.secure.logger] to false
11:00:06,564 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - 
Attaching appender named [sslsocket] to Logger[splunk.secure.logger]
```

**WHAT IS RECEIVED BY SPLUNK WEB**

```
Time    Event
```

3/2/19
9:48:45.000 AM
\xAC\xED\x00
host =  127.0.0.1 source =  tcp:6514 sourcetype =   logback

**In Summary**

From the above, it appears to me that this is not a connection issue, as Splunk is listening to the port 6514 and is able to capture input BUT the captured input is displayed as HEX and not normally.

When I use a normal com.splunk.logging.TcpAppender, my logs are displayed correctly on splunk.

1. Is there any other configuration I may have missed out
2. Is it possible to enable SSL while using the com.splunk.logging.TcpAppender
3. Is there a dedicated Splunk SSL appender that can be used instead of ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SSLSocketAppender
4. Any other suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Any relevant information in any of the logs at `$SPLUNK_HOME/var/log/splunk`? Oh, and since you've enabled debugging in the logback config and didn't mention anything, I'm guessing there is no relevant information output there?

Comment: There are a lot of log files in that location. which one, in particular, should I check?

Comment: In your logback config you provide a truststore so I'm guessing you set up a self-signed certificate. Perhaps looking at `$SPLUNK_HOME/var/log/splunk/splunkd.log` could give some information if that was loaded correctly?

Comment: Here is the Log file: http://eagle-beacon.com/splunkd.log

Comment: I have edited the question and also added the logback debug output to console

Comment: Couldn't find anything related to why this isn't working, but a couple of things might be worth double checking. First, verify that the splunk root certificate is in the trust store your're supplying, as that's the one your splunk setup is using according to the log. Second, check for any error messages when you do the actual logging

Comment: I have checked, and I can confirm that the trust store is in good condition. And I think if the trust store is tampered with, the connection will not be able to happen. But in this case, connection happens and my log gets to splunk. Just that it prints out as hex and not actual words. Sometimes a part of the actual words and hex is printed out. The log happens successfully and there is no error message. When I searched online, some people say its attributed to formatting misalignment e.g UTF-8, ASCII, UTF-16 etc

Comment: I agree with that analysis. Seems like splunk uses/expects UTF-8 by default. Maybe check that the application uses the same encoding

Comment: Application uses the same encoding

Comment: What you're seeing there is a "raw" UTF-8 encoding. Have you read through the [character set encoding configuration documentation](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.2.4/Data/Configurecharactersetencoding)? There's obviously some discrepancies with the encoding. Could be that enabling SSL messes with the encoding at some level (either the appender or spelunk). If I was at a loss as to what to do I would attempt a TCP dump to see exactly what was transmitted

Comment: Yes, I have also set the character Encoding for the port to UTF-8. But the error is still the same. I have now tried something different. I.e to send a String directly from my application using JSSE pointed to my Splunk SSL port. The data is received on the port and displays correctly on splunk. So what I would say is that probably splunk does not work well with the ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SSLSocketAppender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to switch to log4j in order to solve this. With the below configuration in log4j, the logs were displayed correctly on splunk web.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info" name="example" packages="">
<Appenders>
    <Socket name="ssl" host="localhost" port="6514">
        <PatternLayout charset="UTF-8">
            <pattern>%date{ISO8601} [%thread] [%C.%M\(\) - Line %L] [%level] : %msg %ex{short} %n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <JsonLayout properties="true"/>
        <SSL>
            <TrustStore location="/path/to/keystore.jks" password="password"/>
        </SSL>
    </Socket>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
    <Root level="INFO">
    </Root>
    <Logger name="splunk.secure.logger" level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="ssl"/>
    </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```